# How to update a directory of files with GIT LFS?

Tags: git-lfs

When using GIT LFS for to provide precompiled libraries for users, I often need to update the directory with the newly built libraries & headers.

- All files that don't exist in the new build should be removed/untracked.
- All new files should be added/tracked.
- All unchanged files should be left as-is.

How can this be done?

I've found surprisingly little documentation about manipulating whole directories with git lfs, most docs deal with individual files.

---

Note: I tried to remove & untrack a directory, then add and track the new directory but tracking is reporting errors that the old files (removed in the new build) are missing.